# How to transform dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the data I pull in from an external API. SO far, my dataframe looks like this:

```
Country          Date       Team    Rating
United Kingdom  11/8/2019   Team A  95
United Kingdom  2/20/2019   Team B  90
United Kingdom  9/22/2017   Team A  90
United Kingdom  6/28/2016   Team B  90
United Kingdom  6/27/2016   Team C  90
United Kingdom  6/24/2016   Team A  95
United Kingdom  6/12/2015   Team C  100
United Kingdom  6/13/2014   Team C  100
United Kingdom  4/19/2013   Team B  95
United Kingdom  2/22/2013   Team A  95
United Kingdom  12/13/2012  Team C  100
United Kingdom  3/14/2012   Team B  100
United Kingdom  2/13/2012   Team A  100
United Kingdom  10/26/2010  Team C  100
United Kingdom  5/21/2009   Team C  100
United Kingdom  9/21/2000   Team B  100
United Kingdom  9/21/2000   Team B  100
United Kingdom  8/10/1994   Team B  100
United Kingdom  6/26/1989   Team C  100
United Kingdom  4/28/1978   Team C  100
United Kingdom  3/31/1978   Team A  100
```

I would like it to look like this but I'm struggling to figure out how (I'm still new to dataframes):

```
Country         Date    Team A  Team B  Team C
United Kingdom  11/8/2019   95  90  90
United Kingdom  2/20/2019   90  90  90
United Kingdom  9/22/2017   90  90  90
United Kingdom  6/28/2016   95  90  90
United Kingdom  6/27/2016   95  95  90
United Kingdom  6/24/2016   95  95  100
United Kingdom  6/12/2015   95  95  100
United Kingdom  6/13/2014   95  95  100
United Kingdom  4/19/2013   95  95  100
United Kingdom  2/22/2013   95  100 100
United Kingdom  12/13/2012  100 100 100
United Kingdom  3/14/2012   100 100 100
United Kingdom  2/13/2012   100 100 100
United Kingdom  10/26/2010  100 100 100
United Kingdom  5/21/2009   100 100 100
United Kingdom  9/21/2000   100 100 100
United Kingdom  9/21/2000   100 100 100
United Kingdom  8/10/1994   100 100 100
United Kingdom  6/26/1989   100 100 100
United Kingdom  4/28/1978   100 100 100
United Kingdom  3/31/1978   100 100 100
```

So essentially I want the country and date columns to remain the same, however as opposed to having just one team per row, I'd like all teams to appear as columns. Instead of having blank values, I would like their previous value used when not updated.

For example, for 11/8/2019, you can see in my original df that only Team A's rating changes. For the Team B and team C column, I'd like them to use their previous value if it isn't updated.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "Instead of having blank values, I would like their previous value used when not updated." _previous value_ as in chronologically or as in previous row?

Comment: The previous row should have their previous chronological value in it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you need to sort over datetimes, I would suggest to either use the `YYYYMMDD` string representation of dates (e.g. `20191108` for the first record) or to use actual `datetime` data types. Using the American notation is confusing and not easy to sort on.

In any case, to solve your issue I would advise to use pandas [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function first, followed by a *fill NaN* (i.e. [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)) function with a *backfill* (i.e. `bfill`) method.

EDIT: If you want to keep the `Country` column, it seems that using it as a multi-index with the `Date` column won't work with `pivot`. What you can do is to keep the original `df` and join it with the new one on the `Date` column.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt    

# Create DataFrame similar to example
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ['11/8/2019','2/20/2019','9/22/2017','6/28/2016','6/27/2016','6/24/2016','6/12/2015','6/13/2014'], 
                        'Team': ['Team A','Team B','Team A','Team B','Team C','Team A','Team C','Team C'], 
                        'Rating': [95,90,90,90,90,95,100,100]})


# Convert strings to datetimes
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))
df['Country'] = 'United Kingdom'

# Pivot DataFrame
dfp = df.pivot(columns='Team', values='Rating')

# Join with Country from original df
dfp = df[['Date', 'Country']].join(dfp)

# sort descending on Date
dfp.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False, inplace=True)

# dfp is:
# Date        Country         Team A  Team B  Team C
# 2019-11-08  United Kingdom  95.0     NaN     NaN
# 2019-02-20  United Kingdom   NaN    90.0     NaN
# 2017-09-22  United Kingdom  90.0     NaN     NaN
# ...

# Fill NaN values using the "next" row value
dfp.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)

# dfp is:
# Date        Country         Team A  Team B  Team C                              
# 2019-11-08  United Kingdom    95.0    90.0    90.0
# 2019-02-20  United Kingdom    90.0    90.0    90.0
# 2017-09-22  United Kingdom    90.0    90.0    90.0
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks @UJN, is there a way I can keep the country column in the df?

Comment: @nimgwfc check the edit. I can't assure you it will always work with e.g. repeated dates and different countries. Maybe with the actual dataset it would be easier to find a solution, or at least with an example that has some edge cases in it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need is:

```
data.pivot_table(index=['Country', 'Date'], columns='Team', values='Rating').reset_index()\
    .sort_values(['Country', 'Date'], ascending=False).fillna(method='bfill', axis=0)
```

It will create a `pivot_table`, sort the values in the irregular order you have, and pull the last existing values where missing.

Comment: I also thought it was an irregular sorting but then I realized it's just the _hyper confusing_ American English way of writing dates (also, descending in OP case). Edit: Ok, of course you also noticed because of the `sort_values` part of your answer, but I had to rant against this way of writing dates in any case :P

Comment: @UJIN The reason old dates are expected to appear on top, is that they are saved first in a database (if only for the reason that they happened first). So I don't expect the order of date data extracted to be differented than expected, no matter where you live.